# PropertyInfo.GetValueで取得した値がその型のデフォルトであるか調べる方法

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValueで取得したobjectがその型のデフォルト値であるか知りたく質問させていただきました。以下に例を記載します。

```
var returnType = property.GetMethod.ReturnType;
var value = property.GetValue (entity);
// valueが「0」でreturnTypeがInt32であれば、 value == default (int)なのでtrueを返したい
// valueが「null」でStringであれば、 value == default (string)なのでtrueを返したい
```

今までは一個一個判定していたのでもっとスマートなやり方を知りたいです。

```
(returnType == typeof (int) && (int) value == default (int)) ||
(returnType == typeof (string) && (string) value == default (string))
...
(returnType == typeof (byte[]) && (byte[]) value == default (byte[]))
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 趣旨が違うかもしれませんが、「型」ではなく「該当プロパティ」のデフォルト値に関する議論の記事が見つかったので参考に。[記事１](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407337/9014308), [記事２](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8943940/9014308), [記事３](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7068043/9014308), [記事４](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325426/9014308)

Comment: >趣旨が違うかもしれませんが

いえ、添付していただいた記事は私の趣旨と合っていました！（なぜ見つけられなかったんだろう。。）基本的には@flied onionさんの回答通り、値型と参照をチェックしてデフォルト値であるか判定するようなので、見比べて適した答えを探してみます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

構造体はEqualsやメンバ次第かもしれませんが、
以下ではどうでしょう。

```
var returnType = property.GetMethod.ReturnType;
var value = property.GetValue (entity);
if (value == null) return true;
var type = value.GetType();
if(type.IsValueType) 
    return value.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
return false;
```

参照型のdefaultはnullですので、nullであれば初期値です。あとは値型なので実体化した値と一致すれば初期値でしょう。

---

修正しました。だいぶ恥ずかしい間違いをしてしまいました。
nullでない場合は値型か確認した上で実体化したものと一致すればtrue。
それ以外の参照型はfalseです。

Comment: なるほど！「参照型のdefaultはnull」は知らなかったのでありがたいです！ちなみに実体化したものと一致させる必要があるのは「system.void」などの例外を避けるためですか？

Comment: いえ、構造体もあるので実体化した方が早いと思っただけですね。フィールドやプロパティをSystem.Void構造体にはできないように思いますが、なにか手段がありましたか？